# An internal error occurred during: "Setting build path" in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, svn

Good day. I have project on android SDK that used android-support-v4.jar lib. I have an SVN for this project. I code it on Ubuntu and Mac Os Eclipse. So the path for this library is different for Mac os and Ubuntu. On Ubuntu it is all ok, but when I check out project from SVN on Mac and try to change the path for this library in Java Build Path it always take me an error: An internal error occurred during: "Setting build path". What I need to do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Use Eclipse's tool "Add support library". Right click on your project and it should be in the lower part of the menu, perhaps inside "Android tools".

That will include the .jar in your build path and (hopefully) will set a relative path in the classpath so that it's not machine dependant.

I recommend deleting the android-support-v4.jar you placed in the project beforehand, just to make things simpler for Eclipse.

Comment: It takes an error "Add compatibillity library to project" has encountered a problem. Details: Failed
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Have you downloaded the "Android Support Library" package in the SDK Manager? You obviously have some configuration problem in your Eclipse